# How to get current data while cloning using jquery

Tags: jquery, clone, cloning

How to get current data of elements while cloning using jquery. While cloning, it's copy's only the default data in the elements.

Here is the code

```
    souRce.clone()
    .prop('id', newName)    
    .html(function () {
        return $(this).html().replace(RegExp(PrevID, 'g'), newName); 
    })                                                  
    .appendTo(DestiNation);
```

Comment: the problem is not clear.. can you share a sample

Comment: It's not cloning a text box value which i changed after page load. Only default value, that was there on page load is cloning.

Comment: What is `souRce`? You should provide sample replicating issue in question itself.

Comment: For Eg: In the 'souRce', a textbox's value is 'test' in the page load. I changed it to some other value. Then i cloned the 'souRce'. But the textbox in the cloned one (Destination) is having the value 'test'. Not the new value.

Comment: souRce = $('.source');

Comment: The problem is you are overriding the `html` of the cloned element, what are you trying to do with the html... are you trying to change the id/name of elements

Comment: @ajay That's not default behaviour... http://jsfiddle.net/6h8huw19/  Maybe your issue is regarding your regex

Comment: @Arun. You are right. But how can i replace the content of cloned one?

Comment: @ajay Looks like XY problem. Ask question regarding your former issue instead of not working workaround you think would fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, instead of using the cloned element, you are changing its content with the raw html which will replace runtime content with original html markup

So instead of replacing the entire html, just update the `id` and `name` properties like

```js
var counter = 1;

function clone() {
  var souRce = $('.item').eq(0),
    DestiNation = $('#ct'),
    PrevID = 'item-' + counter,
    newName = 'item-' + ++counter;

  var regex = RegExp(PrevID, 'g');
  souRce.clone()
    .prop('id', newName)
    .find('[id], [name]').each(function() {
      if (this.id) {
        this.id = this.id.replace(regex, newName);
      }
      if (this.name) {
        this.name = this.name.replace(regex, newName);
      }
    }).end()
    .appendTo(DestiNation);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ct">
  <div class="item" id="item-1">
    <input name="a" value="A" id="a-item-1" />
    <input name="b" value="B" id="b-item-1" />
    <input name="c-item-1" value="C" id="c-item-1" />
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="clone()">Clone</button>
```

Comment: TypeError: this.name is undefined
 
this.name = this.name.replace(regex, newName);

Comment: So elements dont have name only id and some have only name. no id?

Comment: how to add exception for this?

Comment: it's not happening with the select box. But working for textbox, textarea etc. For select box the value/selectedIndex remains the default one. What can be the reason?